# Can an LED light sold in US be used where voltage is 220?

Tags: electrical, led

The packaging on an LED light does not limit voltage. If it is sold in US can it be used safely where voltage is 220?

Here is an [example](https://www.gelighting.com/led-lights/bulbs/e26/ge-vintage-40w-replacement-led-light-bulbs-amber-edison-style-st19-medium-0)

Comment: You need to provide more information about the light.  Some lights will work anywhere.  Some require 120V.  What does the imprint on the light say?  There will be a sticker or some raised lettering telling you what its power requirements are.  Is this light to be plugged into an outlet?  To be permanently wired into a box?   Does it have a USB charging port?  Etc etc ... need more info.

Comment: Dragging electrical equipment between 120V and 230V zones is, *almost* universally, a verybad nogood terrible idea.  Unless you have rather unique requirements, like someone looking for COTS DC breakers of sane cost, or people in the Philippines wanting GFCI and cost is no object.

Comment: @jay613  I added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for the specific bulb you linked in the question is no.  However, similar-looking bulbs are available for 220V.   Search for "vintage edison led bulb" in the destination country or any 220V country to get one that will work and it's more likely to have an appropriate base for your lighting fixtures there too.

From the "Specifications" on the linked page:
[image]